# Group By inside of subqueries

Tags: sql, group-by, apache-spark-sql

I'm using SQL inside of Databricks. The following query works, but I'd also like to group by a column named sale_id. How would I go about doing that?

```
%sql
select
  (select
     count(distinct time)
  from
    table
  where
    sign_up > 0)
  /
  (select
     count(distinct time)
   from
     table
   where
    action > 0 or
    click > 0)
    as cc3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the query using conditional aggregation:

```
select (count(distinct case when sign_up > 0 then time end) /
        count(distinct case when action > 0 or click > 0 then time end)
       ) as cc3
from table;
```

Then a `group by` is easy:

```
select col,
       (count(distinct case when sign_up > 0 then time end) /
        count(distinct case when action > 0 or click > 0 then time end)
       ) as cc3
from table
group by col;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!